# Google Maps URL parameters - web mercator

Tags: url, parameters, maps

is it possible to request Google Map tiles using something other than Lat/Long?

I'd like to pass the x and y in as web mercator values. I'm not using the Google Maps API and this will be a custom tiled layer where the map object is in web mercator.  I can't use the standard Google Maps URL because that only accepts lat/long values, which won't draw properly on my web mercator map.

Thanks for any assistance.
Ed

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "web mercator values" -- do you mian pixel X and pixel Y?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the Google Map tiles *unless* you use the Google Maps API.  From the Terms of Use at https://developers.google.com/maps/terms :

> 10.1.1. General Restrictions.
>   (a) No Access to Maps API(s) except through the Service. You must not access or use the Maps API(s) or any Content through any technology or means other than those provided in the Service, or through other explicitly authorized means Google may designate. For example, you must not access map tiles or imagery through interfaces or channels (including undocumented Google interfaces) other than the Maps API(s).

Comment: Hi Kaitlin, thanks for getting back. We're paying for the Google APIs where I work so I'll have to clarify if we're still restricted to using their APIs if we want their tiles.  Anyway, I was wondering if we can use local projection values in the URL request, e.g. meters. Do the values always have to be lat/long? Thanks, Ed

Comment: In the Google API, tiles are requested not by lat/lng, but by grid coordinate, and the Google map tile seem to follow the same format: https://mts1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m@210119155&hl=en&src=app&x=1207&y=1542&z=12&s=Gal

Comment: This site shows how the tile grid numbering system works: http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

Comment: You can also convert from whatever coordinate space you are using (e.g. meters) to lat/lng if you need to.

Comment: Hi Kaitlin, thanks for the clarification. I completely forgot that tiles are requested using grid coords. I've got two custom tiled layers in my app and I was trying to figure out why the gmap tiles won't draw while the other one is fine. Looks like it's something else entirely. Thanks again.